# Layering stacked positioned absolute elements

Tags: css

I am trying to create a Quora / Facebook like chat layout where the heights of the messaging system is 100% and covers the whole page. But I have a sample code here and I do not understand why the top part does not show up even tho the z-index is greater.

Basically the top pm-top does not show. Which is a problem that I could not solve.

HTML code:

```
<div class="pm-container">
    <div class="pm-top">pm-top</div>
    <div class="pm-left">pm-left</div>
    <div class="pm-right">pm-right</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.pm-container {
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

.pm-top {
    position: absolute;
    height: 45px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 6px;
}

.pm-left,
.pm-right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    z-index: 5px;
}

.pm-left {
    left: 0px;
    width: 35%;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: green;
}

.pm-right {
    left: 35%;
    width: 65%;
    background: gray;
}
```

I have reproduced the issue here.

https://jsfiddle.net/gLr4r4em/

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: z-index does not have units

Comment: Thank you! I am so embarrassed.

Comment: It happens, Alex! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/gLr4r4em/1/

```
z-index: 6;
```

you can not use px on z-index this must be an integer :)
please mark as answer if so, thanks.

Comment: Please don't badger users into accepting your answers, and if this truly is the answer then the question should be closed instead of being answered. Otherwise when the answer gets an upvote, like it has, the question will no longer be automatically deleted and it will stay until other users come along and clean up your mess. Please only answer good on-topic questions. Questions with simple errors are off-topic

Answer (score -2):

Screw it. if people get down graded for trying to help  let them figure it out.

Comment: The z-index not issue here so really dont matter for this code.You are correct but i just changed what cause 1 solution to issue without worry about z-index.